# After rename a folder, QFileSystemModel and QTreeView return wrong path

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2

[image]

This is a small file manager, you can right-click the tree items to rename them. after renaming the first-level folder, clicking the folder below it will get the wrong path. you can see it at the top of the window, or use this code to check.

```py
index = widget.treeView.currentIndex()
model = index.model()
path = model.fileInfo(index).absoluteFilePath()
```

At the same time, if you rename the second-level folder in that first-level folder multiple times, it will cause strange problems. for example, rename fails or that folder disappears. I think QFileSystemModel is not refreshed after the name change!

The following is the complete code.

```py
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QFileSystemModel, QTreeView, QPushButton, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QGridLayout, QMenu, QInputDialog, QLineEdit
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt, QEvent

class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        ROOT = "F:/New Folder"

        self.treeModel = QFileSystemModel()
        self.treeModel.setRootPath(ROOT)

        self.treeView = QTreeView()
        self.treeView.setModel(self.treeModel)
        self.treeView.setRootIndex(self.treeModel.index(ROOT))
        self.treeView.setColumnHidden(1,True)
        self.treeView.setColumnHidden(2,True) 
        self.treeView.setColumnHidden(3,True)
        self.treeView.installEventFilter(self) # QEvent.ContextMenu

        # for test -----------------------------------
        self.treeView.clicked.connect(lambda index: self.show_path(index))
        treeSelection = self.treeView.selectionModel()
        treeSelection.currentChanged.connect(lambda index, pre_index: self.tree_selection_slot(index, pre_index))

        labelA = QLabel("model path:")
        self.labelA2 = QLabel()
        labelB = QLabel("treeView clicked:")
        self.labelB2 = QLabel()
        labelC = QLabel("tree selection changed:")
        self.labelC2 = QLabel()

        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.addWidget(labelA, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.labelA2, 0, 1)
        grid.addWidget(labelB, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.labelB2, 1, 1)
        grid.addWidget(labelC, 2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.labelC2, 2, 1)
        # for test -------------------------------END.

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addLayout(grid)
        layout.addWidget(self.treeView)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        """ mouse right click rename menu """
        if event.type() == QEvent.ContextMenu and source is self.treeView:

            gp = event.globalPos()
            lp = self.treeView.viewport().mapFromGlobal(gp)
            index = self.treeView.indexAt(lp)

            if not index.isValid():
                return

            menu = QMenu()
            rename_act = menu.addAction("rename folder")
            rename_act.triggered.connect(lambda: self.change_name(index))
            menu.exec_(gp)

            return True

        return super(MyWidget, self).eventFilter(source, event)

    def change_name(self, index):
        """ rename """
        if not index.isValid():
            return

        model = index.model()
        old_name = model.fileName(index)
        path = model.fileInfo(index).absoluteFilePath()

        # ask new name
        name, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, "New Name", "Enter a name", QLineEdit.Normal, old_name)
        if not ok or not name:
            return
        
        # rename
        model = index.model()
        wasReadOnly = model.isReadOnly()
        model.setReadOnly(False)
        model.setData(index, name)
        model.setReadOnly(wasReadOnly)

    def show_path(self, index):
        """ for test """
        if not index.isValid():
            return
        model = index.model()
        path = model.fileInfo(index).absoluteFilePath()
        self.labelB2.setText(path)

    def tree_selection_slot(self, index, pre_index):
        """ for test """
        if not index.isValid():
            return
        model = index.model()
        path = model.fileInfo(index).absoluteFilePath()
        self.labelC2.setText(path)
    
    
if not QApplication.instance():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
else:
    app = QApplication.instance()

widget = MyWidget()
widget.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**UPDATE 1**: new code failed.

[image]

I tried to "rename" several times with the new code, but the problem still exists.
my operation is:

1. rename "Fallout4" to "mass effects". # success
2. then "New Folder-01" to "vol.2". # success
3. "New Folder" to "vol.3". # success
4. "AB" to "BioShock". # success
5. "New Folder" to "bs2" to. # the folder is actually renamed. but the icon of "bs2" became "blank" and can't rename anymore.

all operations are separated by 2 to 5 seconds.

Comment: My system is Windows10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems, both related to the way QFileSystemModel is internally implemented, which preserves a cache of the loaded indexes and node functions (including QFileInfo), adds a [QFileSystemWatcher](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemwatcher.html) for each visited directory and, most importantly, uses a separate thread.

The path issue is related to `QFileInfo` (returned by `fileInfo(index)`), which by its nature does *not* automatically update itself: once a QFileInfo instance is created (and cached, in the case of QFileSystemModel), it doesn't update its data. Since the model presumably associates the index with the QFileInfo, it returns the same (not updated) object. This is also probably related to [QTBUG-33720](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-33720)).

To get the actual path, I suggest you to use [`filePath()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html#filePath) instead (you can use `QFileInfo(model.filePath(index))`, which will create a new and updated instance in order to get the correct name).

The renaming issue depends on the thread part: when setting the `readOnly` property, it takes some time for the "flag to take effect", and doing it right after the QInputDialog doesn't leave Qt enough time for that.  
Note: I'm not really sure about what actually happens and why, but you can check that for yourself: if you use `setReadOnly` *before* showing the dialog, it works.

If somebody with more experience on Qt and C++ might shed some light on this, I'll be glad to know about it and update this answer.
So, as a "workaround", you can change your implementation to the following:

```
    def change_name(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return

        model = index.model()
        old_name = model.fileName(index)
        wasReadOnly = model.isReadOnly()
        model.setReadOnly(False)

        name, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, "New Name", "Enter a name", QLineEdit.Normal, old_name)
        if ok and name and name != old_name:
            model.setData(index, name)
        model.setReadOnly(wasReadOnly)
```

Comment: I did not expect a simple rename action to be so difficult to complete in Qt. I tried to rename it with os.rename() and QDir.rename(), but QFileSystemModel would "lock" that folder. Although model.setData() will not "lock", the result is very unstable, and I always feel that there is something wrong with the internal index. (Although I don't know the real reason).

Comment: I believe you're getting it wrong. `QDir.rename` or `os.rename` really don't care about QFileSystemModel (which cannot "lock" any file, nor it should), and if you're trying to use them with `fileInfo().absoluteFilePath()` then you should *really* read what I wrote with *much more* care. File system management is *not* as easy at it seems just because you're used to it: there are *lots* of layers from your "I want to rename" to the actual result, Qt has to find the right balance between all that (which also happens asynchronously and considers cross-platform issues). You **cannot** ignore that.

Comment: I will do more tests for os.rename later. do you read UPDATE1 above? that's why i said model.setData() is very unstable.

Comment: by the way, how to draw "gray background" on keywords?

Comment: 1) From my tests, if you do what described above, the issue doesn't exist (and, again, if you *really* don't want allow view editing, just set the edit triggers to `NoEditTriggers` and set the `readOnly` property to False from the beginning instead of changing it every time); 2) *again*, what "gray background" and "keywords" are you referring to?!?

Comment: 1) I just want to find a stable and reliable way to change the name. I don't know what "view editing" is. If it is more stable than model.setData() I would certainly use it. I also don't have any concept of "edit triggers". sorry, I taught myself completely from zero basis. 2) see this screenshot.  https://imgur.com/eJBE7qV

Comment: 1) As already said to you, *multiple times*, you **must** study the documentation of the classes you're using. In this specific case, see the [`editTrigger`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#editTriggers-prop) property and its [possible values](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#EditTrigger-enum); "view editing" means double-clicking/key-press to rename an item in an item view; really, please, **study** the classes you're using. 2) Have you tried to click on the "Help" links besides the comments or post editing fields?

Comment: I'm sorry if I look too blunt and seem aggressive or offensive, but, honestly, from **all** your answers and comments, you are still *not* following our suggestions about **patiently** reading and studying the documentation. It's hard, takes *huge* amounts of time and patience, I get it. But that's *the* way. Do you think we got our knowledge from some magic spell? I am completely self-taught on this, I'm not even a professional on this field, I can only do what I do after *tens of thousands of hours* of patience, trial&error, and, most importantly, tiring studying of the documentation.

Comment: The pyside documentation is very different from c++. It seems I need to look more at the c++ version. I appreciate your patience, and I have one last question. It's okay if you don't think it is necessary to answer. Is "view editing" more stable and reliable than model.setData()?

Comment: @g2m.agent For you, yes (with some possible exceptions due to the nature of the model, as explained), and that's exactly what I suggested to you since the beginning: you don't need any dialog or custom function, just use `setReadOnly(False)` since the beginning, and eventually use `self.treeView.edit(index)` to start editing of an item programmatically. Honestly, I stopped using PySide/PyQt docs years ago, they are just limiting and often confusing (that's a missed opportunity, IMHO), and should only be used as reference for the specific cases in which their python bindings behave differently.